# How to convert model to GLTF (.glb) format using AutoDesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I want to use Forge to convert 3d model file format as mentioned on:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/basics/

How can I export to GLTF (.glb) format using AutoDesk Forge API?
There is a sample here:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/

But if I change "type": "obj" to be "glb" format instead then you get format not recognized error. But glTF and glb formats are listed here:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Forge Model Derivative API does not support exporting 3d model file format to GLTF(.glb) format. If you check the doc you mentioned https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/ , "glb" and "gltf" are listed as source file format, which means the 2 file formats can only be translated into the "SVF" format.

Comment: You can use the command line tool OBJ to glTF (from @Cesium), once you have already used Forge Services to create the OBJ file.

- 
http://52.4.31.236/convertmodel.html